# Python - how to read terminal/keyboard while stdin is redirected?

Tags: python, input, stdin

I would like to read from the terminal/keyboard while input redirection is happening:

```
some-command | my-program.py
```

Under Unix I read that I can open `os.ttyname(0)`, but this does not work under Windows (or Cygwin). Is there an OS-agnostic means of doing this? Or is there another approach?

The outcome I want is to be able to detect keystrokes and modify the behavior of my program. The main program just creates one or more threads and waits for them to complete, so I am free to do just about anything in the main thread.

I am using Python 3.6 if that helps...

Comment: use something like `pynput` i think maybe?

Comment: I looked at pynput, but it would then break under linux since it requires X. I could write a module that either uses pynput or ttyname, but I was hoping for something semi-native with a small footprint if possible.